# How to perform full redirection inside IIS (without a browser roundtrip)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler, httpmodule

In the standard redirection scenario, the browser is sending another request to the server.

How to achieve internal IIS redirection with all web application lifecycle events (BeginRequest, AuthenticateRequest, ...) to be retriggered (not just calling the another handler)?

CLARIFICATION: I mean just redirection inside the same web app.

Comment: If I did understand what you mean...it's **not possible** (unless you download the redirect page locally and then you send it back to the client as it was generated on your server). If possible such thing could be a **big security issue**.

Comment: Please, see the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where in the page lifecycle you are. Within a page you can use server.transfer, but it won't work with MVC & it's a bit hacky.

The context has some methods, such as rewritepath that let you change the path that is executing, but again, there are limitations.

iis.net has a [useful article](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing) on this.

Comment: The problem with `RewritePath`, `Transfer` or `Execute` is that it does not perform the full redirection (it does not do the Authentication, Authorization, ...).

Comment: The only way you can trigger those is by starting the request again, as they are part of the request pipeline. That's usually done with a round-trip. I don't believe it's possible to do it without a round-trip